# Export form to xsd file without losing each elements type

Tags: orbeon

When designing a form then exporting it to an xsd file, the type (double, boolean, etc.) of each elements is lost.

In other words :
When targeting this url https://example.com/orbeon/fr/service/project_name/form_name/schema we get the xsd representing the form. Unfortunately, there is no type on the generated elements. https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/api/other-apis/xml-schema-generation

How can we prevent it?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean by exporting to XSD. And for this finding this here, also see this [thread on Twitter](https://twitter.com/Oo_Tsun/status/1113327419816075265), in case it contains more up-to-date information.

Comment: I edited my question. Hope you see what I mean now. I also answered on Twitter. If I get a response on Twitter, I'll copy it here so that this question gets answered for everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was due to a bug ([#4014](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4014)), which is fixed as of Orbeon Forms PE 2018.2.3.

Comment: We deployed the patched version you provide us. The fix is half working : When setting field visibility to true, it works perfectly. Howerver is the visibility is none or "formule", the element in the schema still lacks its type. Could you take a look at it?